# Setting a size limit for Maximizing a Primefaces Dialog

Tags: dialog, primefaces, limit, maximize

I want to make a `Dialog` in my `Primefaces` Page which I can maximize.
But i have one problem. I have a `Menubar` on the top of the page and i want the `Dialog` to **Maximize** over the whole screen but under the `Menubar`.
I also have a `Dock` on the bottom and I want this one to be always in the front.
Are there any possibilities to solve these problems?